# appcompat-v7 dependence returning errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I am trying to import project from eclipso on android studio 0.8.1(beta) and every thing goes right but same errors on appcompat-v7 attr. I have the following gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "package"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":facebook")
    compile project(":socketConnetion")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

when i sync the gradle i keep getting the errors:

```
/Users/tiag`omissiato/AndroidstudioProjects/Get/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.0.1/res/values/values.xml
Error:(432, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropdownListPreferredItemHeight'.
Error:(434, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupMenuStyle'.
Error:(432, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropdownListPreferredItemHeight'.
Error:(434, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'popupMenuStyle'.
Error:(432, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dropdownListPreferredItemHeight'.
```

[...]

any help??

Answer (score 6):

*Moved from an edit in the question*

---

Just to let you know in case same one has the same problem.

in my case was a conflict with a library i am using(`CircularImageView`), that library has a `declare-styleable` named `Theme` that caused my problem, so I changed to `ThemeCircularImageView` and every thing works perfectly now.

And if you don't know where is the `declare-styleable` property : `res` -> `attrs.xml`